# Imprimir matriz aleatoria sin repetir valores min 1 max 3

Tags: java, array, bucle-for, condiciones, random

Necesito imprimir Valores de una matriz aleatoria. 1 a 3.

No se deben repetir valores.

Esto es lo que estoy haciendo. En mi `if` no sé cómo desarrollarlo para la comparación:

```
 String [] Paletas { "chocolate", "cafe","vanilla", "nuez", "coco" ,"fresa"};

   public String getRandom(){
for (String Paleta1 : Paletas) {
    Random r = new Random();
    
    int rnd = r.nextInt(3) + 1;
    
    for (int p=0; p < rnd;) {
        Random rndo = new Random();

 ***AQUI***       
       rndo.setSeed(System.currentTimeMillis());
        int paletaPosition = rndo.nextInt(Paletas.length);
        if (Paletas.equals(Paletas.equals(PaletaPosition)) ) {
            
        }
        numToy++;
        
    }
}
for (String ToyS1 : ToyS) {
    System.out.print(ToyS1);
}
return null;

}
```

Comment: Trata de llenarlo en el main. Una vez con los datos ya puedes seguir el flujo de trabajo para completar lo que estés haciendo

Comment: He intentado editar tu pregunta para mejorar la estructura y la estructura, pero me es imposible corregir las expresiones con las que explicas lo que deseas hacer. ¿Podrías editar la redacción y explicar mejor lo que debe hacer tu aplicación?